# JavaScript - Given 2 classes (A and B), how can I call a method from class B to an instance from class A?

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop

I am working on creating BattleShip using vanilla JS.

1. I have 2 classes - Ships and GameBoard.
2. I have a method in class Ship to accept and validate object coordinates =>
   { x: 'a', y: 2}
3. I also have a method in GameBoard that I am trying to accept a Ship instance coordinate but I am failing to do as these classes not related.

```
class Ship {
    ...

    updateCoord(x, y) {
    ...
    }
}
```

```
class GameBoard {
    ...
    
    placeShip() { // Will be using this method to place ship within the actual game board.
        return Ship.Coord();   
    }

}
```

```
const battleShip = new Ship("BattleShip", ...);

battleShip.updateCoord("c", 2);
```

How can I edit my code so I can call a method from GameBoard to an instance created by class Ship?

```
battleShip.placeShip():
```

Comment: Consider adding a parameter to your  `placeShip()` method.

Comment: you cam inherit one class into another like `class Ship extends GameBoard`. or,
Convert into static method. read more [mdn static docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Comment: "class Ship extends GameBoard" - no-no-no, that's a wrong approach most of the time, @Anilkumar. Inheritance/hierarchies are for object specialization, not for sharing code.

Comment: `GameBoard` should have a property that contains an array of ships. `placeShip()` should take a `Ship` as a parameter, check that there's no overlap with any of the existing ships, then add this ship to the array.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you want to actually merge them,
Below code just example, hope it works the same way as you want

So i assume you want to "assign" this ship to the game board, meaning the game board must know about this ship. hence this code

```
myGameboard.ship = myNewShip;
```

After that assignment, inside the class Gameboard, you could access it by using `this.ship` as shown in example below

After introducing the "ship" to "gameBoard" you could directly use your placeShip function to command the known "ship" to go somewhere by calling that instance function

```js
class Ship {
    updateCoord = (x, y) => {
      console.log({x, y});
    }
}

class GameBoard {       
    placeShip(x, y) {
        return this.ship.updateCoord(x,y);   
    }
}

myNewShip = new Ship();
myGameBoard = new GameBoard();

myGameBoard.ship = myNewShip;

myGameBoard.placeShip(1,2);
```

This also works the same way when you want to call it the other way around which i just realize might be the way you want it based on the last code you show on your question

```js
class Ship {
    updateCoord = (x, y) => {
      console.log({x, y});
    }
    // roundabout way code
    placeShip = () => {
      this.gameBoard.ship = this;
      this.gameBoard.placeShip();
    }
}

class GameBoard {       
    placeShip() {
        console.log("Call your function");   
    }
}

myNewShip = new Ship();
myGameBoard = new GameBoard();

// assigning a gameboard to your ship
myNewShip.gameBoard = myGameBoard;

// Direct Way
myNewShip.gameBoard.placeShip();
// Roundabout Way
myNewShip.placeShip();
```

Enhancement Based on the comments provided about the gameBoard should have more than 1 ship

```js
class Ship {
    updateCoord = (x, y) => {
      console.log({x, y});
    }
}

class GameBoard {       
    placeShip(ship) {
        // If no need to create outside, can create here actually, and remove the param
        // ship = new Ship();
        
        // randomize x & y and add other logic if necessary
        let x = 0; 
        let y = 0;
        ship.updateCoord(x, y);
        //two way connection between ship and gameboard
        ship.gameBoard = ship; 
        return this.ships.push(ship);
    }
}


myGameBoard = new GameBoard();
myGameBoard.ships = [];
ship1 = new Ship();
ship2 = new Ship();
ship3 = new Ship();
myGameBoard.placeShip(ship1);
myGameBoard.placeShip(ship2);
myGameBoard.placeShip(ship3);
```

Comment: It seems like you aren't familiar with the Battleship game, as it has more than one ship on the board.

Comment: If it has more than one battleship, we just need to update the ship to array

Comment: Of course. But you should also change `placeShip()` to take the ship as a parameter and add it to the array. It's quite different from the structure you show, which doesn't even do anything with the ship.

Comment: strictly speaking, i did assign the boardgame to the ship and the other way around on previous code right? which is already solve his problem about "calling" the method from other instance,, my previous answer is solving it by putting the related instance to make use of it when he needs to call the function that's coming from the other class